# need help : python3.5.2 & pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm from Taiwan, and I need help to install pygame.
I've been trying for a long time.
[pygame file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pr63F.png)
[cmd result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhwJp.png)
I want to ask if I download the right pygame file.
If not please tell me which is the correct one.
My computer: Win10 ; 64 byte ; python 3.5.2
Thanks a lot

Comment: is your Python installation 32 or 64 bit? (not your Windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1:**
You have a 32bit install of Python (even if your Windows is 64-bit).

You can check if this is the case by looking at the output of

```
import struct;print(struct.calcsize("P") * 8)
```

if so, you will need to download the 32bit version of pygame not the 64-bit one.

**Option 2:**
Less likely, but it could be an issue with pip, check if you have the latest version installed and install it with:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. As you said, I download the wrong one. I learned a lot this time , thanks for you're help. I finally solve this problem.